# tuple values for a key in scala rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have rdd with key-value pair in Scala. I want to form rdd in such a way that it will be `(key , tuple(values))`.

I have tried using map but did not work. If it is pyspark then I would have used 
`map(lambda x : x[0] , list(x[1:]))`

`(a,1,2,3,4), (b,4,5,6),(c,1,3)` to `[a,(1,2,3,4)], [b,(4,5,6)], [c,(1,3)]`

Comment: Maybe you only need [`groupByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@groupByKey():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,Iterable[V])]).

Comment: That don't solve the problem. Tried already

Comment: `groupByKey` would work for pair tuples and OP has 3-,4-,5-tuples.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, did not understand at the beginning. You may try this `map { t => val iter = t.productIterator; iter.next() -> iter.toList }` However, that would give you a **RDD[(Any, List[Any])]**, which does not seems too useful to me.

Comment: I did try that but I want output such as (a, (1,2,3)) not like (a, list(1,2,3)). Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Krzysztof's answer is what you are after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala tuples are hard to handle in a generic way (it will change in Scala 3), so the most straightforward solution for you would be just to create helper object with overloaded function:

```
object TupleUtil {   
  def splitHead[K,V](t: (K,V,V)): (K,(V,V)) = t._1 -> (t._2, t._3)
  def splitHead[K,V](t: (K,V,V,V)): (K,(V,V,V)) = t._1 -> (t._2, t._3, t._4)
  def splitHead[K,V](t: (K,V,V,V,V)): (K,(V,V,V,V)) = t._1 -> (t._2, t._3, t._4, t._5)
  //etc up to 22
}
```

Or if you can use shapeless, then you could simply do:

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

(t.head, t.tail)
```

To use it, simply add it to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3"
```

Comment: So we can't handle the values dynamically without using helper. Thanks @Krzysztof Atłasik .

Comment: To be specific it is doable (because libraries like shapeless do that), but that's real **High Wizardry** with type-level programming. So you should either use  `shapeless` (which does magic for you) or create helper ;). Scala 3 will make handling tuples easier, but it would take some time until it will be used in Spark.